# C# and WPF - Binding List on ItemsSource on DataGridComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, list, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I want to bind `List` (which contains data from LINQ query) with `DataGridComboBoxColumn` as `ItemsSource`. `SelectedValue` property is taken from other `List` with data for whole `DataGrid`.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DG1" x:Uid="DG1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternationCount="2" SelectionMode="Single" Margin="0,5,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
<DataGrid.Columns>
//...
<DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding MyValueItem}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Source="{StaticResource myvalue}" Header="Values" Width="Auto"/>
```

C#:

```
public class ValuesInfo
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
    public string myvalue { get; set; }
}

public class MyValueItems : List<string>
{
}

public partial class MyWindow : Window
{
    public MyValueItems MyValueItem { get; set; }

    public MyWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();  
    }

    private void MyWindow_Load(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyValueItem = new MyValueItems();
        sqlDataContext dc = new sqlDataContext();
        var allValueNames = (from p in dc.Names
                               orderby p.id ascending
                               select p.name);

        MyValueItem.AddRange(allValueNames);
        DG1.DataContext = MyValueItem;
    }

    public void LoadValues()
    {
        List<ValuesInfo> ValueList = new List<ValuesInfo> { };
        //...

        for (int i = 1; i <= (int)rdr[0]; i++)
        {
            var dbset = (from p in dc.Values
                         where p.id == i
                         orderby p.id ascending
                         select p).Single();

            var ValueName = (from p in dc.Names
                             where p.id == dbset.valueId
                             select p.name).Single();

            ValuesInfo valueItem = new ValuesInfo
            {
                id = dbset.id,
                number = dbset.number,
                myvalue = valueName
            };
            ValueList.Add(valueItem);
        }

        DG1.ItemsSource = ValueList;
    }
}
```

Here are a lot of examples of `DataGridComboBoxColumn` Binding but none of these can  help to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are asking for a property on your DataContext called MyValueItem.

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding MyValueItem}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Source="{StaticResource myvalue}" Header="Values" Width="Auto"/>
```

But you are passing the value of MyValueItem as the DataContext.

```
DG1.DataContext = MyValueItem;
```

You need to set the DataContext to an item with a "MyValueItem" property. Replace the above line with the one below.

```
DG1.DataContext = this;
```

Where "this" is the MyWindow which has the MyValueItem property.

...

Alternatively, you could change the binding to the below, which will take whatever item you pass to it as the binding source.

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Source="{StaticResource myvalue}" Header="Values" Width="Auto"/>
```